# How to traverse through the XML structure in memory and replace child?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Say, I have a document-

```
<something>
  <parent>
    <child>Bird is the word 1.</child>
    <child>Curd is the word 2.</child>
    <child>Nerd is the word 3.</child>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child>Bird is the word 4.</child>
    <child>Word is the word 5.</child>
    <child>Bird is the word 6.</child>
  </parent>
</something>
```

I want to traverse through the document and replace the word "Bird" with "Dog" using XQuery and MarkLogic API's. So far I am able to achieve with the following code-

```
let $doc := $DOC 
  return <something>
           {for $d at $y in $doc/element()
             let $p := <parent>
                       {for $c in $d/element()
                         let $child := if(fn:matches($c, "Bird")) then(<child>{fn:replace($c, "Bird", "Dog")}</child>) else($c)
                         return $child
                       }</parent>
             return $p}
         </something>
```

The result is

```
<something>
  <parent>
    <child>Dog is the word 1.</child>
    <child>Curd is the word 2.</child>
    <child>Nerd is the word 3.</child>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <child>Dog is the word 4.</child>
    <child>Word is the word 5.</child>
    <child>Dog is the word 6.</child>
  </parent>
</something>
```

How can I achieve this without nested for loops? This question was asked before but using XSLT.

Comment: why not use regular expression like **s/Bird/Dog/g** ?  It would complete in linear time in a single pass.

Comment: @wontonimo While it is possible to do string manipulation on serialized XML, it is considered bad practice. It is also much more difficult to make sure you only apply changes where actually needed. With a single-pass string replace it would be difficult to make sure you only change the contents of the `child` element, and not the contents of a different element or attribute. More importantly, there would be no risk of messing up the well-formedness of the XML, by accidentally renaming XML tags, or worse, causing them to get broken or removed.

Comment: @grtjn - agreed, although you could add the xml tag checking into the regex like so **s/(\>[^\<]*)Bird([^\<]*\<)/$1Dog$2/g** , which if you check changing **child** to **parent**, you'll see that it won't modify inside the tags and only the word **child** between tags.

Answer (score 4):

Write a function and use recursion. With the `typeswitch` expression you can check node types at each stage of recursion, and using a [computed element constructor](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-computedElements) you can use a generic template to rebuild every element without knowing its name:

```
declare function local:transform(
  $node as node()
) as node()*
{
  typeswitch ($node)
  case element() return element { node-name($node) } {
    $node/@*, 
    for $n in $node/node()
    return local:transform($n)
  }
  case text() return 
    if (matches($node, "Bird"))
    then text { replace($node, "Bird", "Dog") }
    else $node
  default return $node
};
```

Note that explicitly checking with `matches` is not necessary because `replace` will return the input string if nothing matches.

Comment: add a case for document-node(), and include $node/namespace::* when copying elements for an even better identity transform.

Comment: @grtjn Yes, agreed, I only excluded it for sake of brevity in answering the question. Also, for performance-critical transformations, I try to exclude `namespace::*` unless it's strictly needed because I have noticed that in MarkLogic, wildcarding the namespace axis at every element can be somewhat significant, depending on the size and content of the document.

Comment: $node/namespace::* should look at local declarations only. I'd have to try, but I'd be surprised if that had a big impact on performance. But I'll keep it in mind next time I play around with that..

Comment: @grtjn The performance impact is small. In my case on a paged set of search results about 10 ms. It would only matter in very tight latency-budgeted query, as was the case in that application.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from wst looks very good, but the same question has been asked so often, they created a library to make this easier. It is often referred to as the 'in-memory update library'. An improved version of that can be found here:

https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations

I thought it might be worth at least mentioning it..

HTH!